Unintended Joins between inherited classes with EF Core
When having a class inherit from another class with EF Core, this causes automatic mapping between mappings where no relationship should exist.
I am using EF Core version 6.0.1
I have two tables Cards and CardsHistory. CardsHistory is a history table and contains all of the columns in Cards, but with a few extra such as HistoryId and DateActive.
I represent this in EF Core as a CardsHistory entity which inherits from the Cards entity, with a few extra fields.
Cards looks as shown here. Note, nowhere in this class is there a reference to CardsHistory:
public class Card
{
    int id { get; set; }
    // ...
    int cost { get; set; }
}

CardsHistory then looks like this:
public class CardHistory: Card 
{
    int HistoryId
    DateTime DatesActive
}

The entities are then put in DbSets in a DbContext.
The unexpected behavior happens when I do any query on Card. Currently there is only one card in my database with an id "1". It has been modified once so there are two entries in its history table.
If I do a query such as
dbContext.Cards.Where(c => c.id == 1).ToList()

I expect just one card. I end up getting two cards, one for each entry in the cards history table. This behavior scales with the number of entries for a given card.
Meaning, cards modified 4 times will have 4 cards returned, rather than the sole card I expect to be returned.
I managed to track down the query that is sent to the database with an unintended discriminator block which is listed below.
-- @__p_1='150'
-- @__p_0='0'
SELECT t."Id", ..., t."Cost"
FROM (
    SELECT c."Id", ... ,  c0."HistoryId", CASE
        WHEN (c0."Id" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'CardHistory'
    END AS "Discriminator"
    FROM "Cards" AS c
    LEFT JOIN public_history."CardsHistory" AS c0 ON c."Id" = c0."Id"
    WHERE c."InventoryId" = 30001
    ORDER BY c."InventoryId"
    LIMIT @__p_1 OFFSET @__p_0
) AS t
LEFT JOIN "Products" AS p0 ON t."ProductId" = p0."Id"
LEFT JOIN "Users" AS u ON t."PurchasedById" = u."Id"
ORDER BY t."InventoryId"

I can get the original intended behavior to come back by removing CardHistory from the DbContext.
I can't tell if I am breaking the conventions of EF Core or if I am making an OO mistake defining this relationship. Other posts on stack overflow and other programming sites point to this being some combination of

Tbt vs tbh
Lazy loading
Properly configuring a FK relationship

The relationship is not a FK relationship so I could never implement points 2 or 3. I attempted to configure TBT rather than TBH in the image below but this produced no difference in output.
Image of model builder definitions for Card & CardHistory

Try create BaseCard and derive both classes from this class. Do not map this class during model creating.

I would try to define a FK relationship first. So that one Card has a collection of history entries.
You can also try to configure .HasBaseType((Type)null) on the history type so that EF does not infer a hierarchy there.

To expand on the behavior, EF is implying an inheritance Between card and cardhistory where the OP merely wants the CardHistory to adopt the same fields as the Card rather than an "Is-A" relationship, so you need to break the inheritance as far as EF is concerned with .HasBaseType((Type)null) and explicitly set the CardHistory PK rather than the default Id column. What EF is thinking is a classic inheritance scenario with Animal (base type) and Dog vs. Cat. You do not create an "animal", you create dogs and cats so if you have 2 dogs and 3 cats, if you query Animals you get all 5 back.

As per a comment by Svyatoslav Danyliv

Try create BaseCard and derive both classes from this class. Do not map this class during model creating.

